# Convert Apache POI .jar to .dll using IKVM.Net

Tags: java, .net, dll, apache-poi, ikvm

I'm trying to convert Apache poi .jar to .dll . I used the script below to convert. However I'm getting lot of warnings and error ***Invalid option -resource:poi-3.8-20120326.dll*** after that. Here's the script i used.

```
ikvmc -target:library poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
ikvmc -target:library poi-3.8-20120326.jar
ikvmc -target:library -resource:poi-3.8-20120326.dll poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar
ikvmc -target:library -resource:poi-3.8-20120326.dll poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.dll poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.dll poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
ikvmc -target:library -resource:poi-3.8-20120326.dll poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.dll poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar
```

Is this correct way to use IKVM.Net . If not what is the correct script to do this.

Comment: Please see my answer to the similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14207641/595274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just completed a project where I have successfully converted and used Apache POI 3.9 using IKVM 0.46.0.1. The converted set of DLLs support pre 2007 and post 2007 Microsoft Office formats.

Prerequisites:

Download POI 3.9 and copy all the JAR files into one directory
Download IKVM (I used version 0.46.0.1)
The following commands (run in Windows 7 command line in the same directory where all the POI JARs are) did the trick for me:

```
ikvmc -target:library xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
ikvmc -target:library stax-api-1.0.1.jar

ikvmc poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar -target:library -reference:xmlbeans-2.3.0.dll -reference:stax-api-1.0.1.dll 


ikvmc -target:library log4j-1.2.13.jar
ikvmc -target:library commons-logging-1.1.jar
ikvmc -target:library commons-codec-1.5.jar

ikvmc poi-3.9-20121203.jar -target:library -reference:log4j-1.2.13.dll -reference:commons-logging-1.1.dll -reference:commons-codec-1.5.dll

ikvmc -target:library dom4j-1.6.1.jar

ikvmc poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar -target:library -reference:poi-3.9-20121203.dll -reference:poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.dll -reference:dom4j-1.6.1.dll -reference:xmlbeans-2.3.0.dll
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try once I get back to my pc

Answer (score 2):

The `-resource` option of the [`ikvmc` compiler is documented](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html#Options) like this:

> -resource:name=path    Includes path as a Java resource named name

So that seems to indicate that `-resource` is used to include resource files into the compilation, and not (like you're doing) previously compiled DLLs.

This suspicion is confirmed by this example of how the `resource` option is used in [an example of the ant wrapper around `ikvmc`](http://ant-ikvmc.sourceforge.net/):

```
<resource name="/logs/logging.properties" path="${builddir}/logging.properties"/>
```

Since `ikvmc` is a java-bytecode-to-.net-intermediate-language compiler, it understands how to read jar files. So instead of trying to include the (previously generated) DLLs into the compilation cycle, you should just point `ikvmc` to the original jar files.

The simplest way to do this is probably by converting all jars in one go:

```
ikvmc -target:library poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar poi-3.8-20120326.jar poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the option -resource with -reference.

But the best is to compile it in one step with { } syntax. See the [wiki for details](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Convert_a_jar_file_to_a_dll_and_use_it_as_library). This can look like:

```
ikvmc { -target:library poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar } { -target:library poi-3.8-20120326.jar } { -target:library poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar } ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Frank's answer of converting all the jars in one go solved the problem for me. Here's the full command I used for POI 3.10. All of the jars need to be in the same directory. The -out option allows you to specify the name of the output dll, otherwise it takes the name from the first jar.

```
ikvmc -target:library -out:poi-3.10.dll xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar stax-api-1.0.1.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar log4j-1.2.13.jar commons-logging-1.1.jar commons-codec-1.5.jar poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
```