# How to IKVM Apache POI

Tags: c#, java, apache, apache-poi, ikvm

I want to use Apache POI in my .NET application, I know there is a port NPOI but it's not complete and don't have PowerPoint related functionality.

I've tried to IKVM it by using the following command:

```
ikvmc -target:library poi-3.8.jar poi-ooxml-3.8.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar poi-excelant-3.8.jar poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar
```

but when after using the classes in resulting dll I've executed the application, got this error:

```
The type initializer for 'org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow' threw an exception.
```

can someone direct me to the link where I can download IKVMed Apache POI, Googled it but didn't have much luck as of now.

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft provide a .NET API to work with Mircorsoft Office documents?

Comment: Yes there is but the code provided for Merging powerpoint decks throws error, and Apache POI have a class dedicated to this, I want to try this.

Comment: Did you contact Microsoft support? What do they say about this error?

Comment: Don't you need to include the [dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) too? IIRC, you'll want to pass them in along with the main POI jars all in one go

Comment: I've added each and every jar that's present in the src, in order not to miss any, but still get "Type Initializer" error.

Comment: Which exception with stacktrace do you receive? Do you have some compiler errors? See also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658972/convert-apache-poi-jar-to-dll-using-ikvm-net

Answer (score 4):

I just finished the project where I have successfully converted POI 3.9 using IKVM.

Prerequisites:

- Download POI 3.9 and copy all the JAR files into one directory
- Download IKVM (I used version 0.46.0.1)

The following commands (run in Windows 7 command line in the same directory where all the POI JARs are) did the trick for me:

```
ikvmc -target:library xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
ikvmc -target:library stax-api-1.0.1.jar

ikvmc poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar -target:library -reference:xmlbeans-2.3.0.dll -reference:stax-api-1.0.1.dll 


ikvmc -target:library log4j-1.2.13.jar
ikvmc -target:library commons-logging-1.1.jar
ikvmc -target:library commons-codec-1.5.jar

ikvmc poi-3.9-20121203.jar -target:library -reference:log4j-1.2.13.dll -reference:commons-logging-1.1.dll -reference:commons-codec-1.5.dll

ikvmc -target:library dom4j-1.6.1.jar

ikvmc poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar -target:library -reference:poi-3.9-20121203.dll -reference:poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.dll -reference:dom4j-1.6.1.dll -reference:xmlbeans-2.3.0.dll
```

Hope it helps.